# Status is picklist field when Status is 'Open' only then the Submit Button Display on that Record otherwise Button should be Hide Using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, js

```
        <template for:each={recenttimesheet} for:item="tts">
            <tr key={tts.Id}>
                <td><lightning-input type="radio" name="radioButtonSelect" value={tts.Id} onclick={handleChangeRadio} id={tts}></lightning-input></td>
                <td>{tts.Name}</td>
                <td onchange={handleStatusChange}>{tts.Status__c}</td>
                <td>{tts.Week_Start_Date__c}</td>
                <td>{tts.Week_End_Date__c}</td>    
                <td>{tts.Total_Hours_Logged__c}</td> 
                <td>  <!-- <template if:true={disabledbtn}> --> if i'm putting this then the Submit Button is enable or disable for all record not for one record
                  <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" disabled={disablebtn}></lightning-button> 
                                        <!--   </template> --> </td>
                               
            </tr>
        </template>
```

image----
[image]

Comment: You need that disabled option to be part of the JavaScript object data you are iterating.

Comment: @PhilW yes i mention in js disablebtn but it is hiding for all record and also if we give this false then it is showing for all record

Comment: That's my point: the flag needs to be part of the iterated data, not a standalone flag. You need this boolean value in your "tts" item.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: Phil already did; you need to put the flag into each item in the array, and use `{tts.disablebtn}` instead.

Comment: Hi Sourabh, you can add 1 more variable in  "recenttimesheet" List (Apex or js) like showSubmitButton and assign value on basis of the status. [if status == 'Open ' then showSubmitButton = true].

And put if true on lightning-button not on td because it will not distort the UI.

Comment: If your `recenttimesheet` array is coming from a wire or imperative apex call, just update the handling of the response to 1. [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597588/how-do-you-clone-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) the data and then 2. iterate them to add a new property to each entry, `disabledbtn`, calculated with whatever criteria you need using data from the entry.

Comment: @sfdcfox  I am beginner in lwc so please give one example.

Comment: @KaranSharma I tried your example but didnt work

Comment: @SourabhSinghChauhan can you show me what did you tried.

Comment: @KaranSharma
<template if:true={status}>
                      <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Submit" disabled={disablebtn}></lightning-button> 
                                            </template></td>

js
RecentTimesheet1()
        .then(result=>{
            this.error=undefined;
            if(result.Status__c==='Open'){
                console.log('---status'+this.status);
                this.status=true;
            }
        })

Answer (score 4):

```
<template for:each={data} for:item="tts">
    <tr key={tts.Id}>
        <td><lightning-input type="radio" name="radioButtonSelect" value={tts.Id} onclick={handleChangeRadio} id={tts}></lightning-input></td>
        <td>{tts.Name}</td>
        <td onchange={handleStatusChange}>{tts.Status__c}</td>
        <td>{tts.Week_Start_Date__c}</td>
        <td>{tts.Week_End_Date__c}</td>    
        <td>{tts.Total_Hours_Logged__c}</td> 
        <td>  
            <lightning-button if:true={tts.showSubmitBtn} variant="brand" label="Submit" disabled={disablebtn}></lightning-button> 
        </td>        
    </tr>
</template>
```

before populating recenttimesheet list do this manipulation

```
this.data = [];
this.data = recenttimesheet.map(item =>{
    let showSubmitBtn = item.Status__c == 'Open'
    return {...item, 
        "showSubmitBtn":showSubmitBtn,
    }
})
```

FR : [Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/gyuErezYIty9CRfwYZtv)